# Open VirtualBox GUI?

Tags: virtualbox

I've installed VirtualBox and I would like to create a VM now. I prefer to use the GUI rather than the command line interface, and I know that VirtualBox comes with such a GUI. However, I can't seem to figure out what the name of this application is.

```
$ dpkg -L virtualbox | grep "/usr/bin/"
/usr/bin/VBoxSDL
/usr/bin/VBoxBalloonCtrl
/usr/bin/VBoxManage
/usr/bin/vboxheadless
/usr/bin/VBoxHeadless
/usr/bin/vboxmanage
/usr/bin/vboxballoonctrl
/usr/bin/vboxsdl
/usr/bin/vboxwebsrv
```

None of these applications actually start a GUI. How do I start the virtualbox GUI?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On my Debian at least, the command is `virtualbox`. Your `grep` did not find it because there is no file of that name in the `.deb`, installing `virtualbox` will create a link in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/virtualbox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Jul 21 23:48 /usr/bin/virtualbox -> ../share/virtualbox/VBox.sh
```

It should also be accessible through your window manager's or desktop environment's menu system.

EDIT: The OP pointed out in the comments that on his/her system, they also needed to install the `virtualbox-qt` package.

Comment: Turns out I had to install `virtualbox-qt`, then `virtualbox` showed up in `dmenu` (since I'm using `xmonad`).